# Change popup menu text colors

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Dialog with a custom layout that has an EditText and the popup menu to paste text has a white background (because I changed it) and white text. I want to change the color of the text, but I can't find the XML attribute to change it.

How the popup menu appears

[image: Appearance of the popup menu]

Theme

```
<style name="Theme.Notes" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>

    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorOnSecondary</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorOnPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/onSurface</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/NoteCreation.Dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="NoteCreation.Dialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.MinWidth">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/onSurface</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/onSurface</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/onSurface</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/surface</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NoteCreation.Dialog.Button</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/NoteCreation.Dialog.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="NoteCreation.Dialog.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try to change the value of the atribut `android:textColor=""`

Comment: @ShayKin That doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the dark themed dialog by using Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.MinWidth as the dialog parent, I reckon it would've been fine if I was using a dark mode theme, but I am using Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight for the app. I just had to change the dialog parent to Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.MinWidth.

Answer (score 0):

That way should work. You use a `Popup Window`, so that's how to define the attributes:

```
<style name="Theme.Notes" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF01F0</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#545656</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#545656</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>    
</style>
```

Comment: Give it another shot. You may to tweak some specific attributes, but that's how you define a PopupWindow.